# Pass Arguments to Bash Script when xinetd receive message via udp

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, udp, xinetd

i was wondering if its possible to pass args to a bash script when xinetd receive a command from a random host (in lan) via udp. To clearify: when i send e.g. ***hello*** from a random client to the xinetd server i want the xinetd server to pass the hello to my specified bash script. Same thing with ***world***.

here is my xinetd service file:

```
service test
{
        socket_type = dgram
        protocol    = udp
        port        = 65534
        type        = UNLISTED
        wait        = yes
        user        = root
        server      = /root/sendmail
        server_args = **Received Message from UDP connection**
}
```

Kind regards and thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot receive the message inside your bash script, because there simply is no stream to receive on `stdin`.

Using UDP, you are sending `datagrams` which are handled differently by xinetd.

### Receiving TCP *Streams*:

*xinetd* establishes a connection with your *source host* and forks an instance of your given script.
The `stdin` (standard input) get's connected to *stream* of the *source host*. Then you can `read` the input or do whatever you would do with a locally initiated run of your `sendmail` process.

By the way: The `stdout` get's connected to your *source hosts* `stdin` as well and you can see answers or other messages, if you need bidirectional communication.

### Receiving UDP *Datagrams*:

*xinetd* receives a *datagram* on your port and runs your script before even reading what it received. The (still unconnected) socket will be handed over to your script.

You need to do the full handling of reading *datagrams* by yourself, which is not as trivial as reading and writing *streams*. Also, this usually needs something more than a simple bash script.

(See `recvfrom` and `sendto` if you are interested in doing this)

---

From my perspective I'd recommend you to just switch over to a *TCP stream* for this. This will also ensure that your commands will actually reach your host or throw an exception on your *source host* for futher handling.

**Edit:** This is how your xinetd service would look like:

```
service test
{
        socket_type = stream
        protocol    = tcp
        port        = 65534
        user        = root
        server      = /root/sendmail
}
```